# How to search by field value in Spring Data REST without use the UUID?

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-data-rest

I'm using `Spring Data REST` for the first time and I'm a newbie with this technology.

I have this scenario:

- a web-app that exposes companies and products
- every company can have one or more products

My base implementation seems to working fine.

When I go to the URL: `https ://localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies`

I have this result:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "companies" : [ {
      "companyName" : "Company_Name",
      "companyId" : "1234",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "https: //localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/015d8038-96dc-42cb-94af-1ab49158150f"
        },
        "company" : {
          "href" : "https: //localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/015d8038-96dc-42cb-94af-1ab49158150f{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "products" : {
          "href" : "https: //localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/015d8038-96dc-42cb-94af-1ab49158150f/products"
        }
      }
    },
```

If I go to the URL:
`https ://localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/015d8038-96dc-42cb-94af-1ab49158150f/products`

I obtain all the products of that company.
This is correct, but I want to obtain the same result without using the `UUID` in the URL, with something like: `https ://localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/Company_Name/products`

Below my actual implementation for the Company Repository:

```
public interface CompanyBaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Company, UUID>{

}
```

And this is the Product Repository:

```
public interface ProductBaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, UUID>{

}
```

What implementation should be used to do this task?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean that instead of using uuid you want to use company name?

Comment: exactly, I want to access using the company name and not the uuid.

Comment: first of all are you sure that company name will always be unique?

Comment: Yes, the company name will be always unique

Comment: A client should never(!) construct a link but only use the received ones. So if you don't send links that include the name, how does the client know them? And why should you send links that include the name?

Answer (score 0):

In the spring documentation [here][1]
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.7.x/reference/html/repositories.html

See section 1.3.1 Adding custom behavior to single repositories
Basically what you want to is make a custom interface, make a class which implements this interface and does what you want. And make your ProductBaseRepository extends this as well. So probably you want:

1) Create an interface ProductCustomRepository (here create method to find the products be company name)
2) Create class ProductCustomRepositoryImpl which implements the above interface (here implement method to find the products be company name).
3) Make your ProductBaseRepository extend the ProductCustomRepository as well.

If you need anything more I will add more details but it is very easy and you could manage this without a problem I think.

Comment: Thanks for now, I will start considering this idea!

Answer (score -1):

I have found an alternative way.

I added a method in the CompanyBaseRepository that exposes the search by name:

```
public interface CompanyBaseRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, UUID>{

    @RestResource(path="byName", rel="byName")
    Company findByCompanyName(@Param("company") String companyName);

    @RestResource(path="byId", rel="byId")
    Company findByCompanyId(@Param("company") String companyId);

}
```

The result is obtainable in the URL:
https://localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/search/byId?company=9
or:
https://localhost:8881/my-project/api/companies/search/byName?company=test

Thanks to all!